# While reviewing wanted to edit but couldn't and no notification

Tags: bug, review, edits, notifications

While I was reviewing some Q/A I wanted to edit one of them but the Edit link didn't work

Also no notifications popped up nor a warning of some kind was shown

Then I tried directly outside the Review Tool, loaded the Q/A and pressed Edit and a warning showed telling something like "I had my edit queue pending approval full" so I couldn't tried to edit now

That warning never showed up inside the Review Tool

Right now I have full edit powers so I can't reproduce it, but before 1k rep that happened